# Magento Product Review Error after Submitting

Tags: magento-1.9

Anyone can help me? Can't figure this out. I'm having a problem about magento product review. It always asking me to "Please specify the quantity of products(s)" after submitting the form.

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Hello Japhz, welcome to Magento SE. The error in your question is not clear at all. I suspect such an error will not be raised by review section in default Magento. Are you using any review related extension in your Magento instance ? If yes, put more details about that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems your review page is coming inside add to cart form. I mean form inside form. You need to put your review form outside product add to cart form "product_addtocart_form".